# serverside clustering google maps markers

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, cluster-analysis

I would like to know what is the fastest algorithm for clustering markers in PHP?

Only thing I need from the cluster function is an output with a cluster obj, that has properties: lat,lng and size.

and then the markers that weren't clustered of course, but I can't seem to find php code for this, and there must be some?

I'm looking for the code-behind that would produce this kind of result? (Or perhaps perform better). http://maps.forum.nu/server_side_clusterer/

**So far I've tried with:**

```
function ClusterMarkers($markers,$ZOOM)
  {
  $this->load->library('firephp');    
  $singleMarkers = array();
  $clusterMarkers = array();

  // Minimum distance between markers to be included in a cluster, at diff. zoom levels
  $DISTANCE = (10000000 >> $ZOOM);
  // Loop until all markers have been compared.
  while (count($markers)) {
      $marker  = array_pop($markers);
      $cluster = array();

      // Compare against all markers which are left.
      foreach ($markers as $key => $target) {
          $pixels = abs($marker['lat']-$target['lat']) + abs($marker['lng']-$target['lng']);
          $this->firephp->log('pix :'.$pixels);
          if ($pixels < $DISTANCE) {
              unset($markers[$key]);
              $cluster[] = $target;
          }
      }

      // If a marker has been added to cluster, add also the one we were comparing to.
      if (count($cluster) > 0) {
          $cluster[] = $marker;
          $clusterMarkers[] = $cluster;
      } else {
          $singleMarkers[] = $marker;
      }
  } 
  return array('singlemarkers' => $singleMarkers, 'clustermarkers' => $clusterMarkers); 
  }
```

My data is then jsonized, but the clustermarkers array contains all the markerdata, and I'm wondering how I would effectively simply set a lat,lng and a size without having to recalculate to resourcedemanding everytime a new marker is added.

Comment: @Andy Paton - I edited the question - good point =)

Comment: Although I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve, it would be more efficient if you could rewrite your function so that it doesn't contain nested loops.

Comment: @Robin - I took this snippet from someone else, so actually I don't understand it 100% myself. I too would prefer an alternative solution that would output clustered markers with size, lat and lng, and then the unclustered markers with all data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the `$clusterMarkers` array is a group of clustered markers, so you could simply take the centroid of the containing markers instead of returning all markers. Before returning the result, do:

```
foreach($clusterMarkers as $key => $cluster) {
    $centroid = array('lat' => 0, 'lng' => 0, 'count' => 0);
    foreach($cluster as $marker) {    
        $centroid['lat'] += $marker['lat']; // Sum up the Lats
        $centroid['lng'] += $marker['lng']; // Sum up the Lngs
        $centroid['count']++;
    }
    $centroid['lat'] /= $centroid['count']; // Average Lat
    $centroid['lng'] /= $centroid['count']; // Average Lng
    $clusterMarkers[$key] = $centroid; // Overwrite the cluster with the single point.
}
```

Comment: it's really weird but that add-on makes the serverrequest clog up everything. Firefox and chrome stalls and I have to kill the process if I use that

Comment: @Hamish - Right now only 500, but long term millions.

Comment: @Hamish - but the thread-block is really weird - why would an asynchronouscall no matter how data heavy clog up the system. Maybe it's a javascript error, maybe your script is workin.

Comment: If it's millions then you probably should look at a sturdier GIS solution, like using spatial columns and aggregate queries rather than trying to build the output in PHP. Don't konw why this would clog things up - do you have example code?

Comment: @Hamish - please elaborate on the "sturdier GIS solutioN" are there any links I can check out to learn how to create a better solution?

Comment: well, http://postgis.refractions.net/ for example, or MYSQL spatial queries. It's a big topic.

Comment: @Hamish - that looks really neat. I think i'll go with the MYSQL spatial, but is there functionality to cluster the markers in the spatial api, or would it be better to do that in PHP?

Answer (score -1):

I use the MarkerClusterer JavaScript class from Xiaoxi Wu.

You may want to take a look and adapt it to PHP:

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2009/04/markerclusterer-solution-to-too-many.html

Comment: hey - Yeah, but there's a lot of google functionality and the plugin seems relatively hard to dissect. It seems easier to find some code that will perform this request for me.